# Quickest way to debug Chrome Extension popup scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the Chrome Apps and Extensions developer tool installed to debug my Chrome Extension. However, to debug the popup script running in the popup window, you have to perform the following steps:

1. Refresh the Chrome Extension on the Extensions page
2. Right click the icon next to the url bar
3. Select "Inspect Popup"
4. Set breakpoints

The real annoying part about this is the popup window has to be re-opened every time a change happens. Debugging background scripts I don't have as much of a problem with, because the background script debug page stays open after you refresh the chrome extension. But for popup scripts, the popup window along with the popup debug page keeps closing and it becomes a really tedious, repetitive task to re-open it when debugging a lot. Is there no other way to more easily start debugging Chrome Extensions popup scripts?

Comment: So after looking a bit more I stumbled upon [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c11cd639-2abb-4243-96d2-153c0adb494a) chrome extension plugin for visual studio, where if you hit ctrl+f5 you can run your popup in just the normal browser, which should be fine in most situations. So this is an option for windows users.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you have a pop up while tapping the icon in the URL bar

In order to debug you can use **weinre** remote debugger ,Which may solve your problem

[apache weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)

Comment: I'll take a closer look at this thanks. This seems like it's more geared toward mobile devices though?

Comment: Yes ,But its applicable for desktop as well ,All the best :)